# Restricting access to a Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, containers

I'm trying to look at Docker through a security point of view. Can I restrict user access to my docker container?
I know that a user who isn't in the sudoers list cannot access docker. But, is it possible to obtain container-level access restriction?
for example, user1 and user2 both have sudo privileges and can run docker containers. But, can a container be created in such a way that it is accessible to user1, but restricted to user2?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Look into Docker-in-Docker. Setup your system in such a way that users shell(s) are in fact Docker-in-Docker sessions so that you separate their Docker containers in a way that restricts what they can and cannot see and access.

Answer (score 1):

If a user has sudo privileges, they can effectively access anything on the host, including all devices, files and containers. They could also just sudo to the other user.