# Docker Nginx: Restrict access to container by IP address subnet

Tags: docker, nginx, ip

I already saw [Restrict access by IP in docker nginx container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237829/restrict-access-by-ip-in-docker-nginx-container), and [Restricting access to a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791770/restricting-access-to-a-docker-container) and similar questions.

**Here is the scenario:** There are 15 microservices written in Laravel o*n my computer and localhost* and each microservice has its own NginX container. So there are 15 Nginxes. All Nginxes must be connected together **and they must accept only the requests from another container**. (Not necessary to mention that one of the microservices serves as an API gateway and it is free to accept requests from any IP address). To do so, I created a network as follows

```
docker network create --subnet 120.120.130.0/26 common_network
```

and for every Nginx in `docker-compose` file, I have the following configuration

```
foodlist_nginx:
build:
  context: ./dockerfiles
  dockerfile: nginx.Dockerfile
container_name: nginx
image: nginx
restart: unless-stopped
tty: true
ports:
  - "${MICROSERVICE_A_NGINX_PORT}:80"
networks:       
    common_network:
      ipv4_address: 120.120.130.x
volumes:
  - .:/var/www/html
```

where `x` in `ipv4_address: 120.120.130..x` is a number between 3 and 62. The configuration of `default.conf` is

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    allow 120.120.130.0/26;
    deny all;
}
```

So far everything works well but there is one problem.

> When I send a request to an Nginx from my computer via `localhost:port`, it accepts the request, and I found out that the Nginx of the microservice detects the IP address of my computer as `120.120.130.1` and I don't know why.

I would be grateful if you let me know why the IP address of my computer is `120.120.130.1`

## Update

This is the docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

networks:
  common_network:
    external: true
  foodlist_network:
    name: foodlist_network
    driver: bridge

services:
  foodlist_php:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php8.1.Dockerfile
    container_name: "foodlist_php"
    image: foodlist_php
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    networks:
      - foodlist_network
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "${FOOD_LIST_PHP_PORT}:9000"
  foodlist_redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: "foodlist_redis"
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - redisdata:/dataF
    ports:
      - "${FOOD_LIST_REDIS_PORT}:6379"
    networks:
      - foodlist_network
  foodlist_nginx:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: nginx.Dockerfile
    container_name: foodlist_nginx
    image: foodlist_nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "${FOOD_LIST_NGINX_PORT}:80"
    networks:
        foodlist_network:
        common_network:
          ipv4_address: 120.120.130.6
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - foodlist_php
  foodlist_mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.0
    container_name: foodlist_mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "${FOOD_LIST_MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
      SERVICE_TAGS: "foodlist"
    command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']
    networks:
      - foodlist_network
volumes:
  mysqldata:
    driver: local
  redisdata:
    driver: local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the `ports:` line for things you don't want to be externally visible.  You should also consider deleting the manual IP address assignments, and potentially even all of the `networks:` blocks.

A container normally isn't accessible from outside of Docker, unless you declare `ports:` for it (or equivalently `docker run -p`).  Since that's your essential requirement, you can just use Docker's functionality here instead of trying to figure out manual IP address assignment and IP ACLing.

I might try to reduce this fraction of the Compose file to just:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  foodlist_nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/nginx.Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
networks:
  default:
    name: common_network
    external: true
```

For the networking configuration in particular, I've [configured the `default` network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network) to use the `docker network create` network, then relied on Compose attaching things to `default` on its own.  I do not set `ports:`, so the container won't be accessible from outside of Docker.

As a variation, you can also set up `ports:` so that the container is accessible, but only from the current host and not elsewhere, by telling Docker to bind to the host's 127.0.0.1 localhost interface (note, this is different from the microservice containers' localhosts or any of the Nginx proxies' localhosts).

```yaml
ports:
  - '127.0.0.1:${MICROSERVICE_A_NGINX_PORT}:80'
```